# Making loop using *

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to make a loop using * as my text. Im trying to make my output look like this:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

I am a little unsure how to do this. I currently got:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

   int i=1;
   while (i <= 4)
   {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

this outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
```

can I have some helping changing the numbers to (*) form. thanks,

Comment: Hint: first write an other small program that prints N times a `*`. Once that works you almost have your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, try it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
            for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
            {
                printf("* ");
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are printing value of i which ranges from  1 to 4 and hence such result. For such type of patterns , you usually need to have nested for loop for outer loop deals rows and inner loo-p deals with column. And printf will print the data you want to see on the pattern

You can try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
            for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
            {
                printf("* ");
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Currently, you are only iterating on the number of lines that you want to print. You need another iteration around the number of asterix's that you want to print.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

int i=1;
while (i <= 5)
{
    int j = 1;
    while(j <= i)
    {
        printf("* ");
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using %d with a string, that is hardly correct

Comment: Did you try this code? I do and it doesn't work like this question.